# Set the System Sleep/standby timeout programmatically

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-5.0

I need to set the sleep/standby timeout programmatically for my device.  (ie when it sits idle for a while it turns off.)

It defaults to 120 and I have a tool that let me change it, but I want to change it via my program (dynamically).

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Power Manager Suspend Timeouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa932196.aspx) on MSDN. Make sure to set the global event they mentioned at the end of the article to make the settings take effect.

Comment: Thank you.  That is exactly what I needed.  Care to take a swing at how that event would look? (even code that is close would be nice).  If not I will dig till I figure it out. Either way, Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean how the event would look? How to open it and set it?

Comment: Yeah.  I was referring to how to do what you mentioned as the last line of your answer: "Make sure to set the global event they mentioned at the end of the article to make the settings take effect."  But I figured it out.  I will post the code as an update to my answer when I have tested it.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!